# Need help finding a FPGA Board

Tags: microcontroller, fpga

I'm an engineering student and I'm suppose to order a FPGA Board. They weren't real specific in what I needed. However, all I know is i'm suppose to be able to run the free web version pack "Quartus II".

I would like to be able to hook it up to my Macbook Pro by USB. I have the software "parallels" on my Mac to run Quartus II from Windows 7. So I believe I'm set up for the software portion of it.

If anyone can provide a link to a controller that you believe might work great I would appreciate it. My price range tops out at $200.00. Also if anyone has additional concerns in regards to running the controller on my Mac please let me know. I believe since I have parallels I'm set.

Again, I'm a student and would appreciate any advice you might have for me. Right now I'm looking on mouser and have only found the following. However, I'm not for sure what to get.

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Terasic-Technologies/P0082/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtg8Gw61H%252bsr73U177jghH2

Comment: Quartus II is the development tool for Altera's CPLDs and FPGAs, so that Terasic board should be appropriate.

Comment: While it's a good idea to double check, generally its only the mid-to-high gate count versions of a given FPGA which are not supported by Altera (or for that mater Xilinx)'s free tool version... and boards with those larger chips would probably be out of your price range anyway.

Comment: How can I route USB devices through parallels on my mac for the jtag programmer. Or will I need to go through this process.

Answer (score 2):

For cheap you can't beat the DE0-Nano. It's got a built-in USB blaster and has some LEDs and pushbuttons, and standard 0.100" headers to connect anything else. I have several of these and love them. If you need more, you can look for the the DE2, but it's considerably more expensive.

Don't be afraid to check eBay for a board; you can save quite a bit of money over going through the normal supply chain. The danger of course is getting a board that's been abused, but my personal experience in that regard has shown that to not be as big a danger as it might seem.

Both (and any Altera FPGA board) shoudl work fine with the free version of Quartus. Quartus works fine with Parallels (as it also does with VirtualBox or VMWare Fusion, both in Windows or Linux varieties.

Comment: Will this work. Does it have a USB option       http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=139&No=502

Comment: I don't know the specific requirements for your course, but yes, that's the DE2 board I mentioned. It gives you lots of I/O and has a decently sized Altera FPGA for your course.